# How to evaluate the final result of this parse tree?

Tags: python, algorithm, parsing, tree

I am trying to evaluate the final result of a parse tree (either `True` or `False`). In such a tree, a node corresponds to a logical operator (`AND` or `OR`) whereas a leaf corresponds to an atomic condition that is either `True` or `False`.
I am representing my tree with nested lists:

```
# Generic class from which all operators derive
class Node(list):
    @property
    def label(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__

    def __repr__(self):
        
        return self.label + super().__repr__()

# Subclass for each operator
class AND(Node):
     pass
class OR(Node):
     pass
```

After parsing and evaluating the atomic conditions, I am getting the following object:

```
AND[OR[AND[True, True], AND[False, True, False], AND[True, True, AND[True, False]]], AND[True, True, True, False], OR[True, False]]
```

Of course, for an AND node, all of the conditions must be true. For OR conditions, only one must be true. At the end, I want to get the final result, `True` or `False` that results from the merging of all of this sub-conditions.

Here is the code that I wrote to implement this logic:

```
def evaluate(root, parent = None):
    
    if(depth(root) == 0):
        return root
    if depth(root) > 1:
        return root.__class__(evaluate(item, root) for item in root)
    elif depth(root) == 1:
        operator = root.label
        if(operator == "AND"):
            if False not in root:
                return True
        if(operator == "OR"):
            if True in root:
                return True
        return False
```

My main function is simply calling `evaluate(result)`

The result that I am getting is:

```
AND[OR[True, False, AND[True, True, False]], False, True]
```

I think that what I need now is to do some reverse DFS after evaluating the result of a child. Like deconstructing the nested lists to get the final result at the end.

Any recommendations ?

Comment: An easier formulation of `evaluate()` would be to have it take in a root node and return the boolean equivalent of subtree rooted at the input (no parent node needed). Then in pseudocode `evaluate(root)` would just be: "if root's label is `True/False`, return it. Otherwise, if root's label is an operator, chain the correct operation on `evaluate(child) for each child in root` and return that."

Comment: Maybe I didn't get what you just said but isn't that what I am already doing ? 
You said: " `evaluate(root)` would just be: "if root's label is True/False, return it. ". That corresponds to: 
`if(depth(root) == 0): return root`
and then you said: "Otherwise, if root's label is an operator, chain the correct operation on 
`evaluate(child) for each child in root` and return that." This one corresponds to: 
`if depth(root) > 1: return root.__class__(evaluate(item, root) for item in root)`
Could you be more precise ? Thanks for the answer

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"`. It should help to see if code works as you expcet.

Comment: @furas Is this a real comment? Or are you inherently condescending ?

Comment: yes it is real comment. And this is what I do when I have problem with code. I tried to run your code but it is incomplete so it was the only what I could suggest to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your existing `evaluate` function, this is where the problem is -

```
    if depth(root) > 1:
        return root.__class__(evaluate(item, root) for item in root)
```

At each node, we should be using the `operator` at the node on the value returned by the children of that node.

Here's the corresponding psuedo-code for the `evaluate` function(I can't test it since the full class definitions are missing in the question)

```
def evaluate(root):
    if(depth(root) == 0):
        # would we ever go in this block?
        return root
    elif depth(root) == 1:
        operator = root.label
        if(operator == "AND"):
            return all(root)
        elif(operator == "OR"):
            return any(root)
        return False

    # depth(root) > 1
    if root.label == "AND":
        return all(evaluate(child) for child in root)
    elif root.label == "OR"
        return any(evaluate(child) for child in root)
```

The use of `all()` and `any()` would help in short-circuiting the evaluation early in case we come across a subtree which leads to a definite answer at the given node.

Comment: Thanks, that solves the issue, To answer your question "would we ever go in this block", yes, this condition is true if an a most granular list element is found, namely True or False. 
I found another solution: Keep the same function as I wrote it and do a `while(depth(root)) != 0: root = evaluate(root)` in the main function,  but I assume that your solution is better ?

Comment: If we just use `while(depth(root)) != 0: root = evaluate(root)` wouldn't that go into infinite recursion? We would need to return the evaluated value at the current root in terms of its children.

Comment: It does not go into infinite recursion. The output is the same as the one with your method. Maybe a `print()` inside the `while` loop will be more explicit: 
`AND[OR[AND[True, True], AND[False, True, False]], AND[True, True, True, True], OR[True, False]]` then 

`AND[OR[True, False], True, True]` then 

`AND[True, True, True]` then

`True`

Does that make sense ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. What is your current `main` function from which you are calling the `evaluate` function?

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: ahh ok, you are returning the `root.__class__(evaluate(item, root) for item in root)`, this would be exponential instead of being linear, since you would be evaluating the whole subtree from the current root to the bottom during each iteration.